# Javascript to automatically supply password

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I have an application that displays password protected PDFs using iTextSharp.

> pdfCopy.SetEncryption(true, "Secretinfo", "Secretinfo", 0);

If the user saves the PDF, the saved copy of the PDF is password protected. Which is great. The problem is it also prompts for password before displaying the PDF on the browser. Which isn't good.

So I'm thinking maybe it's possible to supply the password using javascript just to display it on the browser. It's bad practice but I don't see that I have any other choice. I'm no good at JavaScript. Maybe someone here can help me?

But hey if you have another idea of how to best approach my problem, please do tell!

**Here's what I need to happen:**

Display the PDF on the browser without it prompting for password. But I need the saved copy to be password protected. No edit, print or copy. Not even view. Unless the user supplies the password.

Comment: I haven't used Itextsharp but the place where it prompts for password , is it at the browser level? If that's the case you'd need browser add-ons

Comment: Yeah. So what specific add-on would I be needing?

Comment: There doesn't exist a standard cross-browser PDF renderer JavaScript API. Actually, to the best of my knowledge, no browser implements a way to interact with a PDF in any way except for opening. You might be able to use the PDF.js library to render the PDF but you might run into some browser issues. But before you do that, is there a reason that you need to set a password to open in the first place? Couldn't you just disable whatever features that you don't want users to use (print, edit, select, etc.)?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I need the saved copy of the PDF to be basically useless unless the user knows the password b/c they contain confidential information. I wanted to completely disallow saving but I was told that's not possible.

Comment: @Artemis, that makes sense. As you've found out you can't really disable save because in order for a browser to download/view something on the web it has to save the bytes somewhere first (memory, disk, etc). If your requirements are that the PDF be password protected then I can't think of a single cross-browser method of supplying a password when opening the PDF. If this were me I would create a temporary password per PDF view that's easy to read but still complex (`cat45dog@house$`). If you know most users won't be using Adobe Reader you could also frame the it, password on top, PDF below.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Is there really no way to open a PDF in the browser without it asking for password if I set the user and owner password during encryption?

Comment: PDFs being displayed in the browser are a very recent thing and every vendor out there has their own implementation. There's no API spec AFAIK so everyone just follow's Adobe's PDF spec for implementation and then does their own thing. Adobe's official solution to this is as @mkl said, to pay for and use Adobe LiveCycle. Short answer to your question, however: no.

Comment: @ChrisHaas If you'd make an answer out of all these useful comments, I'd be happy to accept that as the answer to my question.