# Open password protected pdf with php

Tags: php, pdf, password-protection

I just want to know if it's possible to add a header for the password in **php**.

Here is my code

```
$file = '../../files/'.$pdfName.'.pdf';
$filename = $pdfName.'.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to your post , because I am not sure whether I understand your problem . do you want to read a password protected pdf file . your code downloads it .

Comment: No, you cannot pass along a password in the HTTP response for a PDF viewer to automatically open it.

Comment: The password must be entered manually by the user. Also read the comments to the question [Javascript to automatically supply password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719629/javascript-to-automatically-supply-password).